# Apache2 "Require all granted" doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a fresh install of Apache2 on Debian testing and configured a virtual host in a directory like this:

```
<Directory "/path/to/project">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

However it shows me a 403 Forbidden error when I access it and the error log shows:

```
[Mon Sep 23 22:07:57.249276 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 8599] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:49057] AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied
[Mon Sep 23 22:07:57.249349 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 8599] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:49057] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
[Mon Sep 23 22:07:57.249361 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 8599] [client 127.0.0.1:49057] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /path/to/project/some_file
```

Why is it showing *"result of Require all denied: denied"* if I'm using *"Require all granted"*?

They files are readable by any user and just in case I tried changing the owner to Apache (www-data) without luck. Also, the default host on `http://localhost` works normally and phpmyadmin in `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` works too.

All help I've found on the Internet is about replacing the Order directive with Require. I've already done that. What could be the problem now?

Comment: It looks correct to me. Are you sure they isn't some other directive that's more specific with a Require all denied?

Answer (score 5):

Here are two things to try:

1) Run `apachectl -t` to check the *syntax* of your file is valid.

2) Run `apachectl -S` to show which *files* are being parsed.

For example, you may be editing /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf and that's it right? ...but if you run apachectl -S you might see:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
```

ie. The virtual host is overriding your httpd.conf, and may contain its own `Require all denied` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

You have set up authorization, but no authentication. So while the 'Require all granted' will give all authenticated users access, your users don't actually authenticate.

Comment: So where should you set up authentification ? Not very clear ...

Comment: While technically correct, this doesn't answer the question. `Require all granted` specifically allows all access and doesn't need any authentication. There's no point to authenticating when you're metaphorically throwing the doors wide open.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the `AllowOverride All` directive, you may also have an `.htaccess` file in `/path/to/project/`. This one may contain an overriden directive.

Check also if you don't don't have some other parameter in a VHost for exemple.

Comment: I was struggling with this error.  After lots of reviewing all Apache configuration files I found a .htaccess file with invalid content.  None of the messages pointed to this.

Answer (score 1):

After having installed Wampserver 32, I have had the same issue of being rejected by Apache.

I have checked and try to modify the `httpd.conf` file in many ways for 3 days with no luck, going all around the Apache tutorials and Internet forums with the famous error:

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration

I was quite sure I did not define any VirtualHost and none was to be seen in the httpd.conf file.

Finally, I configured the server for "debug" error file, which gave me the more interesting message:

> AH01626: authorization result of Require local : denied

which in turn lead me to this post.

And there it was, hidden in the `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file: an undesired VirtualHost with an explicit "Require local" which of course rejected all my queries from outside the server.

Now, I have emptied this file until I may need any VirtualHost, and it works fine.
In the end, I find it rather strange from Wampserver to not only pre-configure this file without notifying the user but to set the default value so that the "server" cannot serve anything.

Answer (score 1):

This looks really old, but I came today after being desperate for 10minutes. It turned out: Directory and DocumentRoot to be different(misspelled). Maybe this will save some time to someone else :)