# Need to allow only specific file extensions via Apache config

Tags: apache-2.4, permissions, apache2, httpd.conf

I'm struggling with allowing only specific file extensions via Apache (2.4.58).

I'm doing this in httpd.conf.

The problem is if I deny all files at first either like that:

```
<Files *>
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

or just `Require all denied` within required `<Directory>` and then enable what I need like this:

```
<Files ~ "(.html|.php|.js|.css|.png|.jpg|.gif|.ico|.pdf)">
   Require all granted
</Files>
```

This seem to be disabling the directory index logic and when I navigate to a directory Apache no longer redirects to index.php, unless I target the index.php in the URL directly.

There's an option to try to list all extensions to block, but I don't like it, because in general it is unknown. And I'd like to use the principle of least privilege here and base restricition on explicitly allowed list instead.

So how can I do this but still preserve the directory index functionality?

Comment: AFAIK duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/541171/apache2-require-all-granted-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, resolved this

```
<FilesMatch "((^$)|(^.+\.(html|php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|ico|pdf)$))">
       Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

using hint from [FilesMatch configuration to Restrict File Extensions served](https://serverfault.com/questions/648262/filesmatch-configuration-to-restrict-file-extensions-served?rq=1)